# Send civicrm email receipt immediately for recurring contributions - Authorize.net

Tags: civicontribute, authorize.net

I am using drupal, civicrm version 4.7.27.  I would like email receipts from CiviCRM to be sent immediately for recurring contribution, rather than waiting for Authorize.net to process the credit card overnight.  In previous versions, there was code in the file CRM\Contribute\BAO\Contribution\Utils.php that I could comment out, to override the default behavior for receipt.  This was the code I commented out: 
//Do not send an email if Recurring contribution is done via Direct Mode
//We will send email once the IPN is received.
//if (!empty($paymentParams['is_recur']) && $form->_contributeMode == 'direct'){
//  return TRUE;
//}

This code no longer exists.  Can anyone tell me if there is a way in version 4.7.27 to force CiviCRM to send a receipt immediately for a recurring contribution, even if it has not yet been processed by Authorize.net?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could probably achieve this with the CiviRules extension? The extension can be found here: https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules/version-113 and the documentation here: https://docs.civicrm.org/civirules/en/latest/

Comment: Yes that should work